# How to use Vuex in large Vue apps

Tags: vue.js, architecture, vuex

Vuex is great and too much greatness is not always good.

So how much Vuex is too much Vuex? And how much prop drilling is too much prop drilling?

Let's imagine the following module about editing a contact. How would you share data between your components? Would you rather use Vuex or props with multi-level event emitting?

- Please, consider this an **abstract example**, don't suggest changing the structure of the module:

[image: image showing the module structure]

- ContactEdit GETs the data from the server.
- ContactEditAvatar shows non-editable part of the data (e.g. the
  avatar of the contact)
- ContactEditForm shows the editable data and allows the user to edit
  it.
- ContactEditSubmit contains the submit button, that POSTs the newly
  edited data.

How would you pass data around?

There are four options to approach this:
[image: image showing the four options]

**Provider/inject** is not considered an option, as it is not recommended for two-way data binding.

We can also eliminate **option 3** immediately as it doesn't expose the edited data from ContactEditForm to the submit button in ContactEditSubmit.

But what about 1,2 and 4?

**Option 4** keeps all components small, logic is placed next to corresponding template and everything is beautifully modularized.

However, this approach can potentially make tracking data changes a struggle, after the app becomes bigger, so **option 2** is a great alternative, because all the module logic is in a single component and anything can be traced easily.

Props and events should also be able to do the job (**option 1**) and on first sight it actually looks easier and more intuitive.
However, I feel this approach is not scalable enough and can cause real headaches when unexpected changes on the components come in the future. Also, too much props make the code harder to read, imo.

Personally, I would go with **option 4**, but what do you, guys, think?

Please, when posting your response, share your experience with large-scale SPAs.

Thanks and have a great and productive week ahead